# Android MediaPlayer not stopping by clicking alternate button

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have an MediaPlayer with many Sounds. Here is my app in Google Play store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.logtainment.ungesoundboard. Note: the app is in German. When you click on two buttons you hear two sounds. How can I stop the first sound and play the second sound or when I play the first sound, that the second sound stops? How can I create this? Here my Media Player code:

```
public class SoundsZweiActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    MediaPlayer runtergeholt;


  //This is When I click on The button
    public void runtergeholt(View paramView) {
        this.runtergeholt.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sounds_zwei);

        //MediaPlayer
        this.runtergeholt = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.runtergeholt);

        //Toolbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

I hope the Community help me!

Comment: runtergeholt.pause () or .stop()

Comment: @AHoneyBustard  i'd like when i click a second or third button that the last clicked button with another mediaplayer stops!

Comment: No my Problem is not solved. Im in the college in 6 hours i'll be back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've downloaded your app and, made a quick implementation of how I would do it with 3 Buttons, since I've noticed your bad english I also commented important parts in german :

EDIT : Thanks to @Trinimon heres an even cleaner solution with just one MediaPlayer :

```
// implement View.OnClickListener :
public class SoundZweiActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sounds_zwei);

        createButtons();

    }

    private void createButtons() {
        // put your Buttons in an Array and set OnClickListener on all
        Button[] buttons = new Button[]{
                (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_runtergeholt),
                (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_kranke_lache),
                (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_missgeburt),
                // etc ...
        };
        for (Button button : buttons)
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void createMediaPlayer(int id) {
        // Here the MediaPlayer is killed and a new one created, I dont call .stop() and then
        // .start() again because it often crashes when the mediaPlayer is not prepared yet,
        // for example when clicking different Buttons really fast

        // Hier wird der MediaPlayer zerstört
        // und ein neuer erschaffen, wenn man .stop() und wieder .start() ruft kommt es vor dass
        // der MediaPlayer noch nicht bereit ist, falls man z.B. ganz schnell
        // hintereinander verschiedene Tasten drückt stürzt er oft ab

        if (mediaPlayer != null)
            mediaPlayer.release();

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, id);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Determine which button is clicked and play its sound
        // Hier wird gecheckt welcher Knopf gedrückt wurde und der dazugehörige Sound gespielt
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btn_runtergeholt:
                createMediaPlayer(R.raw.runtergeholt); // plays first sound (runtergeholt)
                break;
            case R.id.btn_kranke_lache:
                createMediaPlayer(R.raw.kranke_lache); // plays second sound (kranke_lache)
                break;
            case R.id.btn_missgeburt:
                createMediaPlayer(R.raw.missgeburt);// plays third sound (missgeburt)
                break;
            // etc ...
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // kill mediaPlayer
        if (mediaPlayer != null)
            mediaPlayer.release();
    }

}
```

Comment: @A Honey Bustard +1 looks much cleaner; only one little improvement I can think of: you could  reassign the data source instead of recreating a new player, using `AssetFileDescriptor file = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResourceFd(id);`, `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file, file.getStartOffset(), file.getLength());`

Comment: Sounds great but how? .setDataSource wants a FileDescriptor not AssetFileDescriptor as first parameter. Can it be casted?

Comment: I try to implement it!

Comment: Need I an onClick in my MainActivity.xml? Can i delete this: http://puu.sh/guvqH/c638aa488b.png and this: http://puu.sh/guvs2/cf76f9996e.png

Comment: Yes if you do it as I suggest you can and should delete that, that is really ugly code ;), and no you dont need an onClick in your xml for that to work

Comment: Now, i can't play any sounds! Here an Screenshot: http://puu.sh/guwbS/3f68fa6d68.png , http://puu.sh/guwdQ/80fa251d67.png , http://puu.sh/guwgs/ad680aef73.png , http://puu.sh/guwig/20b6eb7624.png

Comment: @AHoneyBustard one Question! Now i have more than 300 music files. i have the files stored in my res folder with this my app is 200mb big. Can i upload the files to dropbox and play this?

Comment: post this as a new question, I'm sure its possible, just not if its a good idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do this
`firstmediaplayer.stop();`
after start the Mediaplayer runtergeholt.

Comment: I would like when you press a button, the last played sound or who is still playing stops @WilliYe

Answer (score 0):

I'd add an [`OnCompletionListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html), stop and release the player here as well:

```
runtergeholt.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        ...
    }
```

**Note**: releasing the player is quite important, from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release()): *"... this method should be invoked to release the MediaPlayer object, unless the application has a special need to keep the object around. ..., failure to call this method immediately if a MediaPlayer object is no longer needed may also lead to continuous battery consumption for mobile devices, and playback failure for other applications if no multiple instances of the same codec are supported on a device."*

Comment: Where can I implement it? @Trinimon

Comment: Right after creation of the media player, i.e. after `this.runtergeholt = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.runtergeholt);`

Comment: This is not what he wants, this waits for the sound to complete, he wants the sound to stop on Click while playing

Comment: Yes I know, but he didn't include any buttons in the code and adding an `OnClickListener` which calls `runtergeholt.stop();` seemed too simple to me ;) _p.s._ there is no need to have lots of `MediaPlayer`'s. you could also reassign the source.